# How to go back to previous route?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

First of all, I'm not setting my routs in the MaterialApp like this

```
new MaterialApp(
  home: new Screen1(),
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
    '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(),
    '/screen2' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(),
    '/screen3' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen3(),
    '/screen4' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen4()
  },
)
```

Instead, I'm routing from different places in my app by pushing new rout like this:

```
Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        Screen3(someInputData)));
```

How I can pop screens from the current one into screen number 2 for example?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Asumming:  Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> Screen4

When you open the `Screen2` , you could do something like this:

```
    Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Screen2(),
                settings: RouteSettings(name: '/screen2')),
          );
```

And when you want to go back from `Screen4` to `Screen2` :

```
 Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/screen2"));
```

If you just want to go back to the previous screen use:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: I have read [this](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/), [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) and [this](https://medium.com/@kpbird/flutter-introduction-of-routing-and-navigation-49738dbd6abe) but no one mention the settings attribute, Thanks for your answer it's really helped me :)